# Set Image To 100% Width - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using Bootstrap v5, I want to make a header that spans the entire width of the container. I've combed the site but none of the solutions work for me.

```css
*{
      box-sizing: border-box;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    
    .no-padding {
      padding-left: 0;
      padding-right: 0;
    }
```

```html
    <header>
      <div class="container-fluid no-padding">
        <img 
        src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1536782376847-5c9d14d97cc0? ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1356&q=80" 
        class="img-fluid" 
        alt="...">
      </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just add the Bootstrap class mw-100 to the img

Comment: I thought that would work as well but it had no effect. The image has whitespace on the right and the size just stays constant.

Comment: Set a class on the container like img-container and then in css set the background-image to your picture.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp